# jQuery submit hidden form to database

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In jQuery I get a variable from an api named "bank_account_uri" and I need to save this into my rails app User table. in the column customer_uri. However, I don't know how to get this information into my database in the correct way.

The API gave this as an example.

```
    var bank_account_uri = response.data['uri'];
    $('<input>').attr({
       type: 'hidden',
       value: bank_account_uri,
       name: 'balancedBankAccountURI'
    }).appendTo($form);
    $form.attr({action: requestBinURL});
    $form.get(0).submit(); }}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to do it? What don't you know how to do? Store data in a database or post information to your server?

Comment: I don't know how to post this variable to my server in a hidden form in the user table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code they've provided seems pretty sound. To take through you through what it does:

```
var bank_account_uri = response.data['uri']; // Store the response in a variable
$('<input>').attr({ // Create an input
   type: 'hidden', // make it hidden
   value: bank_account_uri, // set its value to your bank_account_uri
   name: 'balancedBankAccountURI' // give it a name, to pick up the server-side
}).appendTo($form); // Add it to a form, this doesn't exist
$form.attr({action: requestBinURL}); // Set url of where the post to
$form.get(0).submit(); }} // Submit the form
```

From this you'll need to add 2 extra variables:

1) A form variable/HTML element:

```
var $form = $("<form></form>").appendTo("body"); // Create & append to body
```

2) A URL of where to post the data to:

```
var requestBinURL = "/mypage";
```

I'd also remove the `.get(0)` part of the final line of code

Comment: Surely if you've already got a site you know this? Just post to your page and if url == '/x' -> userModel